# How to dismiss or suppress permission issue automatically related to Contacts, Camera, Microphone in iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iosdeployment

I have been working on a project wherein i made a framework where i automatically test the SDK my company is developing.

I have created my dummy sample application for all the platforms(iOS, Android, OSX, Windows) which makes use of this SDK and i thereby test this SDK, call the SDK API's do my work.

Now my question is for iOS i get permission alerts for Contacts, Camera and Microphone first time whenever i use the API's of my SDK which internally is invoking something in iOS framework. Is there a way i can automatically give this permission to my application ?? i know it's iOS own Security concern and it's correct. But how do i bypass it.

I see there is Apple's XCUITest framework but i don't want to open my application via it.

Right now i handle this alert manually but i need to implement Continuous Integration(using ios-deploy), i have done everything but i can't handle these alerts automatically.

Can someone please help me.. Thanks!!

Comment: No,You can't do anything with out user permission for camera and Microphone.This alerts will come when you run the code first time.

Comment: Hmm... i know... I was just thinking may be there is a way i can get rid of this to implement my continuous integration process

Comment: No, Apple will not allow this process.